# SQL to select brand from a table, if another table has a product with that brand

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Using MySQL and PHP.

I have two tables products and stock.

**products** has { productID | product | brand|}

**stock** has { ID | storeID | productID | qty | price }

I need to get all of the brands available at a specific store.

So here is what I have that doesn't work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT brand 
  FROM products 
 WHERE 'products.productID' = 'stock.productID' 
   AND 'stock.storeID' = 1
```

If I remove the compare "WHERE" it returns all of the brands.

Comment: Single quotes are only used around string literals, not identifiers like table or column names. You're literally asking the database to compare the words "product.productID" to "stock.productID", not any tables or columns. Don't confuse quotes with \`backticks\`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
Select p.brand FROM products p, stock s 
WHERE p.productID=s.productID and s.storeID='1'
```

Comment: This worked great, just needed to add the **DISTINCT** after **SELECT**.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.brand 
FROM products p inner join stock s on p.productID=s.productID
WHERE `stock.storeID` = 1
```

mark the diff between ` and '

Comment: I am getting the following error even though the column does exist.

**#1054 - Unknown column 'stock.storeID' in 'where clause'**

Comment: -1 `stock.storeID` shoud be  `stock`.`stockID`.  wrap with two backticks one around table name and other on column name  not on the complete tablename.columnname ( `.` should be exclude )

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 "SELECT p.* FROM Products p 
 INNER JOIN stock s USING(productID)
 WHERE s.storeID = '".(int)$givenID."' 
 GROUP BY p.brand";
```

Answer (score 0):

We can write this way also

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.brand FROM products p , stock s where  p.productID=s.productID(+) and stock.storeID = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.brand 
FROM   products p 
             INNER JOIN stock s 
                  ON p.productID=s.productID
WHERE s.`storeID` = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help

```
select p.brand 
  from product p, stock s 
 where p.productID = s.productID
   and s.storeID = 1
```